# What does it mean by 'felt right into the corner' here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Harry enjoyed the breakneck journey down to the Weasleys’ vault, but felt dreadful, far worse than he had in Knockturn Alley, when it was opened. There was a very small pile of silver Sickles inside, and just one gold Galleon. Mrs.Weasley **felt right into the corners** before sweeping the whole lot into her bag. Harry felt even worse when they reached his vault. He tried to block the contents from view as he hastily shoved handfuls of coins into a leather bag.
>
> *Harry potter and the chamber of secrets*

I guess 'right' here is just an adverb (as in *He walked right into the trap*), so what does it mean by 'feel into the corners' here??

Is it an idiom to express one's feelings? Cause Mrs.Weasley *felt* something.. or did she just literally feel the corners (of the vault inside)? But it doesn't make sense to me, either. I cannot picture someone feeling the corner..(???) Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mrs. Weasley stretched her hand all the way ('right') into every corner of the vault and felt around there.

JKR implies that she was hoping to find to additional coins in the corners which could not be seen in the shadows; that, at least, is how Harry understands her action, since he feels 'dreadful' on Mrs. Weasley's behalf to witness the Weasleys' poverty and attempts to conceal his own relative wealth.